# Now icons after power glitch while booting

Tags: boot, 22.04

While booting up Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I had a power glitch. Now I don’t have icons. Browser works. Can not access Terminal.
Any way to reinstall icons without access to terminal?

Comment: Press CTRL+ALT+T to open a Terminal and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` to make sure your system is fully updated. Reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: I would go to a tty (ctrl+alt+F4) and `sudo apt install --fix-broken`. Also check system logs (`journalctrl`) and _SMART Data & Self-Tests_ on _Disks_ app

Comment: Indeed, SMART and error correction would be my follow-up suggestion.